# Animate.css lazy load on scroll

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I'm trying to make animation on a div that loads only when the div is scrolled to the point of view using Animate.css. other libraries, like "AOS" have this option already built in like

```html
<div data-aos="fade-up">
    <!-- any text here -->
</div>
```

I want to apply the same but using [Animate.css](https://animate.style/). An already implemented functionality for AOS library can be viewed on [my website](https://ahmedmahfouz.me/?p=home)

Comment: You need JS for this. Read up about IntersectionObserver: when your element intersects the viewport by x amount you add the class to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in Animate.css library, you must use Javascript.

**Out of the box**, I have made a library called Animate.css-dynamic which allows you to animate element whenever you want. You can use any of the animationis defined in Animate.css.

[Demo](https://kodingkhurram.github.io/animate.css-dynamic.demo/)

[Github](https://github.com/KodingKhurram/animate.css-dynamic/)